# Why can we replace dependent variable y with the residuals/error term e?

Tags: matrices, vectors, least-squares, economics

I don't understand why we can replace $y$ with $e$:

[image: proof]

> As in the proof of the Gauss-Markov theorem,
> $$ \tilde{\beta} = [\,(W' W)^{-1}W' + C\,][\, W\beta + e\,] = \beta + (W' W)^{-1}W'e + CW\beta + Ce $$
> So that $E(\hat{\beta}) = \beta$ if and only if $CW=0$.
>
> The residual component is:
> $$ \tilde{e} = y - W\tilde{\beta} = y - W [\,(W' W)^{-1}W' + C\,]y =  \color{réð}{[\,I - W(W' W)^{-1}W' + WC\,]e} $$

Mainly, why can we simply replace $y$ with $e$, given that $y$ is defined as:

[image: y definition]

> $$\begin{array}{llccc} y = W\hat{\beta} + \hat{e} & = & \hat{y} & + & \hat{e} \\ && T\times 1 && T\times 1\end{array} $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $C$ represent, by the way? To show the result, I suppose the approach would be to replace $y$ by $W\beta+ {e}$ and show that $\left(I - W(W'W)^{-1}W' + WC\right)W\beta = \mathbf{0}$. It looks like $CW = 0$ is being assumed for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, indeed we assume `CW = 0`. I would also replace `y` with `Wß+e` but they aren't that is the part I don't get...

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: How do you know they are not (implicitly) substituting that? I mean, isn't it assumed somewhere (maybe early on in this topic (I'm assume it's to do with Linear Regression)) that we assume that $y= W\beta + e$? If not, where was the symbol "$e$" (without a hat on top) first defined?

Comment: From my econometrics textbook, it is from my professor, thus only used in my university.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, we definitely defined `y = Wß + e`, but nonetheless I don't understand the step from which results in the red underlined expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** For simplicity, let $H = W(W'W)^{-1}W'$ (the "hat matrix"). Note that $HW = W$ (make sure you know why!) and try and show that $$\color{blue}{(I-H+C)W = O}$$ (the zero matrix). This is enough to imply the result, because the result is that $(I-H+C)y = (I-H+C)e$, or equivalently that $(I-H+C)(y-e) =\bf{0}$ (and recall that $y-e = W\beta$).

Comment: Got it, thanks so much!